# ajaxToolKit autoCompleteExtender OnClientItemSelected

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind, autocompleteextender

I am trying to implement an autoCompleteExtender into my project. Currently I am using the OnClientItemSelected property to call a javascript on the client side. Is there a way (using another property or some other code) that will let me call a method in the code behind when the user selects an option?

Answer (score 1):

```
function AutoCompleteEx_OnClientItemSelected(sender, args) {
     __doPostBack(sender.get_element().name, '');
}
```

On server side handle `TextChanged` event of extended textbox.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to return the list from web service method with ID and Text

Here **"lst"** is the actual list with data from your data source.

```
List<string> items = new List<string>(count);
        for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
        {
            string str =AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender.CreateAutoCompleteItem(lst[i].Text,Convert.ToString(lst[i].IDValue));                
            items.Add(str);

        }
        return items.ToArray();
```

Then simple javascript

```
function GetID(source, eventArgs )
    {
        var HdnKey = eventArgs.get_value();
        document.getElementById('<%=hdnID.ClientID %>').value = HdnKey;
    }
```

and dont forget to set the attribute in auto complete extender
**OnClientItemSelected="GetID"**